# Extending code completion to support internal orm

Tags: intellij-plugin

As said in the tittle, i need to extend code completion to support a internal ORM.

It's something like ActiveRecords. Ex.:

```
@TableName("ONE_MODEL")
public class OneModel extends BaseModel {

}

...
OneModel oneModel = OneModel.getById(1);
Object value = oneModel.get("COLUMN_NAME");
...
```

So, when using smart completion when caret between quotation marks inside de .get method, for example, i need to show parameters options based on the table columns.

Something like that it's possible to be made with Intellij Plugins?

I was reading about CompletionContributor, but can't find anything about the possibility to identify the class whose method is being called, it's super class, and it's annotations values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CompletionContributor` is the way to go. This example is taken from the [official SDK docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/completion_contributor.html):

```java
public class SimpleCompletionContributor extends CompletionContributor {
  public SimpleCompletionContributor() {
    extend(CompletionType.BASIC,
           PlatformPatterns.psiElement(SimpleTypes.VALUE).withLanguage(SimpleLanguage.INSTANCE),
           new CompletionProvider<CompletionParameters>() {
             public void addCompletions(@NotNull CompletionParameters parameters,
                                        ProcessingContext context,
                                        @NotNull CompletionResultSet resultSet) {
               resultSet.addElement(LookupElementBuilder.create("Hello"));
             }
           }
    );
  }
}
```

The second parameter of `extend` allows you to trigger your provider on a specific kind of PSI element. In your case, you could target something like `PlatformPatterns.psiElement(JavaElementType.LITERAL_EXPRESSION)`, then in your `CompletionProvider` you can check for the exact element with `parameters.getPosition()` and see if it's a `PsiLiteral` representing a `String`.

Using the PSI API, you can then discover what's around this literal, like classes if the containing file is a `PsiClassOwner`, or with `PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType()` etc.

In your specific example, you could check if the string literal is part of a `PsiMethodCallExpression`.

To easily understand how the PSI tree is built, I highly suggest you open `Tools > View PSI Structure...` and paste a sample of what you want to detect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very much, for the detailed answer.

I'm looping through parents until find a PsiMethodCallExpression element, then i using the .resolveMethod().getContainingClass(). But it gets the super class BaseModel (where the .get method is declared), not the subclass. Any tips?

Comment: Don't mind, already found a way:

`
PsiReferenceExpressionImpl referenceExpression = (PsiReferenceExpressionImpl) parent.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
                                PsiClassReferenceType classReferenceType = (PsiClassReferenceType) referenceExpression.getType();
`